# Automatically delete data from Firebase Database

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have seen some other questions asked but I am having trouble getting it to work. I have a Mac app coded in swift and it has a Firebase login but the user types a key in that is stored on Firebase, is there a way to automatically delete that key when the user has successfully used it?

This is my database.

[image: datbase]

This is the code that is used currently.

```
import Cocoa
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class LoginViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textUsername: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textPassword: NSSecureTextFieldCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnLogin: NSButton!
    var keyArray = \[Int64\]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    override func viewWillAppear() {
    }
    func getLoginState() -> Bool{

        let state = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isRegistered")
        if (state) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }

    }
    override func viewDidAppear() {

        let state = self.getLoginState()
        if (state){
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier(rawValue: "loginsegue"), sender: nil)
            self.view.window?.close()
        }

        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let keyRef = ref.child("key1")

        keyRef.observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            //    let postDict = snapshot.value as? \[String : AnyObject\] ?? \[:\]
            let keyStr = snapshot.value as? Int64
            if let actualPost = keyStr{
                self.keyArray.append(actualPost)
            }
        })
    }

    @IBAction override func dismissViewController(_ viewController: NSViewController) {
        dismiss(self)
    }
    @IBAction func close(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.view.window?.close()
    }
    @IBAction func onSignup(_ sender: Any) {
//        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier(rawValue: "gotosignup"), sender: sender)
//        self.view.window?.close()

    }
    func dialogOK(question: String, text: String) -> Void {
        let alert: NSAlert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = question
        alert.informativeText = text
        alert.alertStyle = NSAlert.Style.warning
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
        alert.runModal()
    }

    @IBAction func onLogin(_ sender: Any) {
        //self.btnLogin.isEnabled = false
        var isKey = false
        if (!self.textUsername.stringValue.isEmpty) {
            for key in keyArray{
                if(Int64(self.textUsername.stringValue)! == key)
                {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:"isRegistered")

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier(rawValue: "loginsegue"), sender: nil)
                    self.view.window?.close()
                    isKey = true
                }
            }
            if (!isKey){
                self.dialogOK(question: "Error", text: "Invalid Key")
            }
        } else {
            self.dialogOK(question: "Error", text: "Please Input Key")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with cloud functions? So I can write an answer

Comment: no :/ I'm not great at coding, I paid someone to create this for me.

Comment: Cool. Can we move this conversation to skype? (rawandahmad10@outlook.com) I'm sure i'll be helpful

Comment: Firebase isn't compatible with the macOS natively - the API is iOS only. Perhaps it's a third party library? Can you elaborate on that? Deleting a key is super easy but can you provide more detail about how you know a user as used a key? e.g. they type it in and at what point is it considered used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sort your database like that and expect a working code, even if there's any. It will make a messy code:

> You need to:
>
> - Sort your database like [1220:0]. the key first. 0 & 1 as an indicator if it's used or not.
> - Once the user taps `onLogin()` you need to set the used key value to 1
> - Setup Cloud Functions to check if the used key is equal to 1, if yes. then remove the key.
>
> Do the rest of the work.

Related Articles to get you started:

- [Extend Realtime Database with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions)
- [functions.database.RefBuilder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onWrite)

Comment: Thank for your attempting to answer. However, that's a lot of effort to remove a key from Firebase. It's actually one line of code if you know the key you want to remove; in Firebase setting the value of any key to NSNull() will remove the key, or you can just use a built in function. So either a non-swifty *refToRemove.setValue( NSNull() )* or just *refToRemove.removeValue()*. If you don't know the key, you can query for the value (which returns the key) and then remove it.

Comment: @Jay. We spent 4 hours via TeamViewer and I was finally able to solve his problem. This is just an answer for future times